# Error WP при переносе на сервер

Tags: php, wordpress, сервер

После переноса из демо-сервера(все работает ок) на рабочий сервер WP выдает ошибку:

> /**
>    * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
>    * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
>    *
>    * @package WordPress
>    */
>   /**
>    * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
>    *
>    * @var bool
>    */
>   define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
>   /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
>   require( dirname( **FILE** ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );`

Подскажите пож как исправить?

Comment: Перезалейте еще раз файлы

Comment: Пробовали, результат был такой же.
Проблема решилась, дело было в том, что на новом рабочем сервере не было PHP, его можно включить в разделе WWW домены на сервере. Пример можно посмотреть [здесь](http://radikal.ru/lfp/s41.radikal.ru/i093/1010/98/260adb3055c4.jpg/htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас PHP на сервере не обрабатывается. Либо поддержка PHP не включена, либо ещё что-то

Answer (score -1):

У Вас в неправильном формате открылся индексный файл. Вам сообщается, что данный файл не выполняет никаких функций кроме подгрузки хедера с шаблона. 
Вариантов решения Вашего вопроса может быть несколько. Для начала проверьте файл .htaccess. В нем должно быть указано:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Если это не поможет - попробуйте установить стандартную тему с репозитория wordpress и открыть с ней Ваш сайт. Если с ней сайт работает - можно попробовать частично заменять элементы Вашего хедера соотв. частями со стандартной темы.

Comment: все это проверил, дело не в этом, сам сайт рабочий и на демо сервере работает корректно, есть у меня подозрение на сам рабочий сервер.